# "This template requires a minimum SDK version" -Android Eclipse ADT plugin reports wrong min SDK.

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I just imported my old Android Project that I just checkout from my git repo.

When I try to create a new Master/Detail Flow Activity using Eclipse :

```
New > Android > Android Activity > Login Activity > Next
```

The Eclipse reports me error saying :

```
This template requires a minimum SDK version of at least 3, 
and the current min version is 1
```

Where as my actual entries in my `AndroidManifest.xml` is :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

I am using `Android SDK Tools` of version `23.2` and `Android SDK Platform-Tools` version `19.0.1`.

Comment: did you try cleaning your project ?? or else do this, as you said you got it through git...delete the manifest and get the manifest again into your workspace and clean the code again. Just giving in my 2 cents here .......

Comment: Okay, thanks. I tried everything you said did not work, but I tried to close and open the eclipse project and it worked. Crazy! :-)

Comment: yes and thats equivalent to cleaning the project. Cleaning / Opening and closing does mostly the same thing all the way except that cleaning also rebuilds the workspace whereas opening and closing refreshes it. Well happy that you got through !

Comment: whenever I came through such kind, cleaning multiple times helped and I had no clue then why it worked...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like Eclipse does this when you refactor your code that affects entries in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

So, before doing anything else `Close` your eclipse project from workspace and `open` the project again by double clicking it. This will force Eclipse to reinitialize your project and will also run Lint & Other checks.

If this doesn't work, try any of the above things suggested by other users.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Lint rule triggered only by the current version of the tools (likely this is something that was added, of the severity was changed in the rule-set).

You can disable this rule in the Lint Perspective, or by right-clicking on it from the Android XML editor.

Not sure what the actual fix is (hopefully someone will answer) - this will silence it, so your build works (but you should really fix the original problem).

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. I tried closing and opening the project. Now its working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Android manifest file. When this happened to me there were obvious errors in the file.